# Unexpected segmentation fault working with small numbers in an algorithm

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I'm working with a statistical algorithm and keep getting a segmentation fault, and  I just can't see it. I'm pretty sure I've calloc'd the memory correctly. I'm wondering if maybe it has something to do with underflowing, as I only get the fault after a few iterations of the loop. Code is below, along with my `printf`'s for debugging. Sorry if the syntax is a bit confusing here, I'm following along from a journal publication.

```
// *** n and m defined previously
float *aux_arr = calloc(n, sizeof(float));
if (aux_arr == NULL) {
    printf("calloc failed");
}

int j;
int j0 = 1;
int j1 = 1;
aux_arr[1] = 1;

for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    printf("\nOUTER\n");
    j1 += 1;
    printf("i: %zu\n", i);
    printf("j1: %i\n", j1);

    for (j = j1; j >= j0; j--) {
        printf("\nINNER\n");
        printf("j: %i\n", j);
        printf("j1: %i\n", j1);
        printf("j0: %i\n", j0);

        // print first 5 elements of my aux_arr
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("%f\n", aux_arr[i]);
        }

        aux_arr[j] = (j/m) * (aux_arr[j]) + (1 + (1/m) - (j/m)) * (aux_arr[j - 1]);


        if (aux_arr[j] < (1.0 * pow(10, -20))) {
            aux_arr = 0;
            if (j == j1) {
                j1 -= -1;
            }
            if (j == j0) {
                j0 += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
OUTER
i: 0
j1: 2

INNER
j: 2
j1: 2
j0: 1
0.000000
1.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000

INNER
j: 1
j1: 2
j0: 1
0.000000
1.000000
1.000000
0.000000
0.000000

OUTER
i: 1
j1: 3

INNER
j: 3
j1: 3
j0: 2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

You can see that the problem comes when I try to access my `aux_arr` for the third time. I'm not sure why it works fine the first two times though.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?  That is the 1st thing to do.

Comment: Could you expand your sample code into a [complete program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and paste, compile, and run?

Comment: It's confusing that you're using `i` as the iteration variable in the outer loop and the loop to print the first 5 elements.

Comment: [You need to use a debugger / some debugging techniques for this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: Why do you multiply `pow(10, -20)` by `1.0`? That has no effect.

Comment: What will this do `aux_arr = 0;`?

Comment: Of topic: `j1 -= -1;` seems a bit strange. Why not `j1 += 1;` or just `++j1;`

Comment: Yeah, there are a few weird quirks about this code (some of which are my fault). I was adapting it from an old and poorly explained journal article, so I need to fix some stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aux_arr = 0;
```

That's your culprit. You are setting `aux_array` to be the null pointer, and the next access is hence invalid.

Comment: Well spotted :-) Maybe `aux_arr[j] = 0` was intended

Comment: Indeed it was supposed to be `aux_arr[j] = 0`. Very simple and yet I just couldn't see it.